# Android emulator isn't starting

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've installed the `SDK` from `android.com` then I manually installed `android-15_r03.zip` (copied at: `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms`) and `sysimg_armv7a-14_02.zip` (copied at `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\System-Images\android-15`) from 
[www.hariadi.com](http://www.hariadi.com). When I make an `AVD` and run it it doesn't start, only a screen named `5554:AVD` is opening with a pad at its right side and android doesn't start loading. The screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

if you start emulator first time it's required time to start boot almost 10min for each screen.You have to wait at least 20 to 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

Wait longer ... the emulators take some time to load especially first time.

On another note I'd move you sdk from

```
  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
```

into something less problamatic

```
  C:\Android\android-sdk\
```

Android doesn't like spaces in its path it'll bite you later on

Comment: I'VE WAITED FOR AN HOUR BUT IT DOESN'T AFFECTED.

Comment: did you wait so long that your caps lock broke?